# Can I download Apps without WiFi connection on my phone?

Tags: apps

I want to download some apps without WiFi but my phone (HTC with Windows Phone 8) is requesting a download over WiFi because of the bigger sizes of the apps. How do I use mobile data to do the downloads?

Answer (score 4):

If an app is too large (over 50 MB, I believe) you must use Wi-Fi to download it. There is no way to use mobile data. You can either find somewhere that offers Wi-Fi, or create a hotspot from another device that has an internet connection.

Comment: Technically there's a configuration entry somewhere controlling this - on WP7 it was in a file that was downloaded periodically from your mobile operator, not sure where it is on WP8.x - but normal apps don't have the privileges needed to edit most of the file system or registry, so it probably wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Well.... I use this trick to go with app downloads and updates. But you'll need two phones to do so. I have a Lumia 535 and a 950XL. I turn on the data of 950XL and then open hotspot which is then received by 535 as a regular Wi-Fi connection. And for 950XL I use the data connection of 535. I've searched it a lot but this is the only way you can do so. You simply cannot download apps over the data connection of the same phone you want to download apps to.

Answer (score -4):

Do the followimg things
1)download uc browser
2)search appx4fun.com on uc browser
3)select the app you want to download
4)press install
5)on the next page press windowd mac
6)after the download is finished reboot your phone
7)open store then click on the options(...)
8)there u can see 'install local apps'
9)the app will be downloaded

Comment: This option to install apps from an .appx file is currently not available on latest update of WP8.1 and W10 mobile. In other words it has removed by Microsoft.

Comment: www.appx4fun.com is an old website having no option for new update of apps i.e.2016 apps so u will waste ur data by downloading it.so sad  for wp users (**)